# How can I get LOL match detail using RIOT API from Java's RestTemplate?

Tags: java, resttemplate, riot-games-api

I am trying to access [RIOT API](https://developer.riotgames.com/apis) in Java using Spring's RestTemplate class. For some reason, I get a response code 500 and I can't determine why.

---

The code trying to call the api:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

String matchString = restTemplate.getForObject(
    URI.create("https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/EUN1_3119578792/timeline?api_key=" + Consts.API_KEY),
    String.class);

System.out.println(matchString);
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 Server Error: [{"status":{"message":"Internal server error","status_code":500}}]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpServerErrorException.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:172)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:782)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:740)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:714)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:333)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

---

This looks strange to me because when I call the same URL using the browser or Intellij Idea's http client, I get the correct json response without any internal server error.

```
{"metadata":{"dataVersion":"2","matchId":"EUN1_3119578792","participants":["9oLEhIbu5RP6HITfkJDnEy5WKOEof4Zg4TJ7GLI7ysxjzSsCpAOyyiFitA86RBpW6Tjm6l1hJHql1g","2G74UyXYGrgzOVJyhlnLvL-MBqSCOW59o1uX8KmmvDsjMeiQhrye1X6ByjmpBcIBzjNOLDZ0bExw5Q","YCqBU2zeTXQhKd9LyNn048Orj8zn2ePa2JoB7U66ql0HsVpurENBRN39HfwnmVCAr0iPX6YnvgFLFA",...
```

---

Moreover, using the same java code for a different RIOT API's endpoint works fine:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

String matchString = restTemplate.getForObject(
                URI.create("https://eun1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/GargamelSmrdi?api_key=" + Consts.API_KEY),
                String.class);
System.out.println(matchString);
```

Standart output:

```
{"id":"_M1uK8Th4G262XkT0f9PVjUk_Dx96C4R3e7vSidKs0z5mfg","accountId":"QW10TRynWV0Zw48DrYqvO_KerzFepBCNOoUWtQHP2BFgdJZNlhtEPKXk",...
```

---

I am lost. Do you have any idea what could be causing this internal server error and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you verified the request via cURL or Postman?

Comment: @thinkgruen I previsously only tried the browser and Intellij Idea http client. Now I also tried to call the same URL using curl from command line. All three methods work fine and I receive a correct json response

Comment: could it be that the servers are just down atm? https://developer.riotgames.com/api-status/ 
MATCH-V4 is down completely, SUMMONER is up however.

Comment: @thinkgruen MATCH-V4 is deprecated I think. I use MATCH-V5. The servers are not down because the same request works when sent from browser or curl. It just does not work from Java

Answer (score 2):

I spent an afternoon finally solving this problem. You just need to use this request header.

`HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); headers.add("Accept","*/*");`